# Send file to windows share via vfs

Tags: vfs, wso2-esb

I am setting up a file transport in wso2 ESB 5.0.0. I have an inbound-endpoint picking up files and calling a sequence called TestSequence to write te same file to a windows share:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="TestSequence" onError="FaultSequenceEmail" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME')" name="SendFileSequence"/>
    </log>
    <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/soap"/>
    <property expression="get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME')" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>    
    <send>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="vfs:file://///Testserver\Test" trace="enable"></address>
      </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

This configuration throws the following error:
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not create file "file://///Testserver\Test/xmltest.dd.lock"

The server folder has read and write rights for the service user running WSO2 as a service.

Doing the same but to a local folder does work. 
`<address uri="vfs:file:///c:/Testfolder\test" trace="enable"></address>` does work

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "smb" is missing in your url. Try with :

```
vfs:smb://Testserver/Test
```

If it doen't work, define a local user on Testserver and try with :

```
vfs:smb://Testserver\user:pass@Testserver/Test
```

(where the first occurence of "Testserver" is the name of the local domain)